# Unable to scroll textview content

Tags: android, textview, android-nestedscrollview

I need show a scrollable error log in a CardView within a Recyclerview that is inside a NestedScrollView

What I tried so far;

Trying to make textview scrollable

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/errorLog"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="120dp"
 android:fontFamily="monospace"
 android:scrollbars="vertical"
/>
```

and set movement method to ScrollingMovementMethod()

Non-editable Edittext

```
<Edittext
     android:id="@+id/errorLog"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="120dp"
     android:background="@null"
     android:editable="false"
     android:cursorVisible="false" />
```

- TextView inside a NestedScrollview
- TextView inside a ScrollView

None of them worked for me

Comment: Try this `textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());` And try putting `android:Maxlines="AN_INTEGER"`` this in the XML

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun still not working inside card view